# Merge a WiFi network with a LAN network

Tags: networking, lan, wifi-configuration

In my office I have two Internet connections. On the first floor I have LAN connection and on the second floor a WiFi connection. Both LAN & WiFi connection ISP providers are different.

I have a local server on the first floor connected to the LAN. All the LAN users can connect to it but the WiFi users can't.

I want to merge the LAN & WiFi connections so everyone can use the local server. How do I do so?

Comment: You can do this with network hardware, depending on the server you may also be able to do this from the server os. Please update your question with the server hardware/serverOS and models of both devices you want interconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, get some advice from a professional network/IT company.

If you want to do this properly you're going to need a network device/modem/router that provides multiple WAN connectivity. These allow multiple WANs to be connected together for such purposes as failover, increased bandwidth and bandwidth/traffic separation.

The device can then allow you to create a single (or multiple, via VLAN technology) network where you can combine your LAN and wifi and allow routing between the two (or make one, big network) allowing your LAN and wifi devices to talk to each other **and** use one or both of the Internet connections.

Such devices, off the top of my head (and from previous experience) are DrayTek Vigor multi-WAN routers.

[image]

You'll see an example image above (source: https://www.dsl-warehouse.com/images/draytek-vigor-2920vn-connections.jpg) showing WAN1 and WAN2 which are the separate ISP connections (Ethernet so you can use your ISP equipment but plug them into the DrayTek with minimal configuration) and the four gigabit LAN sockets allowing you to have up to four separate LANs or (from what I can recall) up to 10 (or 20) VLANs between the Ethernet and wireless networks.

You can even create multiple wireless networks so you can have, say, a guest and a staff network and they'll be completely safe from one another.

Comment: You can then use the router device ports to span your network with trees of switches and access points, as necessary, and use VLANs and trunks to build your desired network infrastructure... As a recommendation: if you're planning a network across multiple floors, consider multiple APs on both floors and, of course, network sockets so you can have a central hub room(s) per floor etc etc.